# iOS Dictionary, add every nth value of one array to each key of dictionary

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

This is my first SO question, forgive me if its a stupid one but I's stumped..

I have 2 arrays, one of which contains only numbers (0 - 10, for example), the other of which contains a larger number of strings (lets say, 50 for this example).

Is it possible to create a dictionary using the keys from the (smaller, numbers) first array and values from the (larger, strings) second array?

part 2 (mostly independent of the first)
Ultimately, I'd like to use this dictionary for UITableView sections but I am also wondering if this is the appropriate or most efficient way to populate sections in a UITableView.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**
A dictionary stores key-value pairs, and the keys have to be unique. So if your 1st array stores (your example) 11 `NSNumber` objects representing the numbers 0 to 10, you have 11 different keys, and you can only associate 11 strings from the other array with these keys.

**Question 2:**
A sectionized table view has 2 indices, the section number, and the row number within a section. Together they are represented as an `NSIndexPath` object. So a natural choice of a data structure holding the table views data is an array storing the sections, where each entry is an array storing the rows of that section.

Comment: Excellent. I appreciate the response. Thanks for your help understanding the difference (Q. 2)!